# issue withweek_of_year() function in obiee11g

Tags: obiee

I have an issue in obiee11g.The function week_of_year() would retrieve week number as 2 for the date '04-01-2016' but should be the first week in 2016.How can i calculate it as first week of 2016 as the requirement is to display this weeknumber.and also all the other week numbers should work fine.Is it abug in obiee11g?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Time dimension which will calculate and load a Time (or Date) dimension. In Oracle Fusion applications, this is called "Date Leveling". I'm not sure what it's called in the BI Admin tool.

Either that, or add the appropriate logic in BI Answers to offset the Week number appropriately.